# Missing newline for adding with bulk API

Tags: elasticsearch

I want to add the following file to Elasticsearch using the bulk API:

```
{"_id":{"date":"01-2007","profile":"Da","dgo":"DGO_E_AIEG","consumerType":"residential"},"value":{"min":120.42509,"minKwh":0.20071,"nbItems":6.0}}
```

using the command

```
curl -XPOST -H 'Content-Type: application/json' localhost:9200/_bulk --data-binary Downloads/bob/test.json
```

but I got the following mistake:

```
{"error":{"root_cause":[{"type":"illegal_argument_exception","reason":"The bulk request must be terminated by a newline [\n]"}],"type":"illegal_argument_exception","reason":"The bulk request must be terminated by a newline [\n]"},"status":400}
```

**NB: The file clearly has a empty line at the end**

Answer (score 2):

In the docs it says:

> NOTE: the final line of data must end with a newline character \n.

There is an example above that of what the document is expected to look like. https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-bulk.html. Perhaps adding `\n` at the end of each line would fix the issue.

**UPDATE:**

There might be something wrong with the way you have placed your data into your JSON file. For example, the following data is in `example.json`:

```
{ "index" : { "_index" : "example", "_type" : "doc", "_id" : "1" } }
{ "field1" : "value1" }
<space here>
```

When running the following `curl` command, it works:

```
curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/x-ndjson" localhost:9200/_bulk --data-binary "@example.json"
```

It could be that you're not including something important in your JSON file, or you don't have "@your_file.json", or like the other poster mentioned, you don't have the content-type as `application/x-ndjson`.

Comment: I tried this:{"index":{"_id":"53e23f5ae4b0ef99cb360835"}}\n

Comment: I tried this: {"index":{"_id":"53e23f5ae4b0ef99cb360835"}}\n \n

Answer (score 2):

The answer is very simple

```
{ "index":{  "_index":"schools_gov", "_type":"school", "_id":"1" } }
{ "name":"Model School", "city":"Hyderabad"}
{ "index":{  "_index":"schools_gov", "_type":"school", "_id":"2" } }
{ "name":"Government School", "city":"Pune"}
```

is not going to work but the below json will work

```
{ "index":{  "_index":"schools_gov", "_type":"school", "_id":"1" } }
{ "name":"Model School", "city":"Hyderabad"}
{ "index":{  "_index":"schools_gov", "_type":"school", "_id":"2" } } 
{ "name":"Government School", "city":"Pune"}
//Give a new line here. Not '\n' but the actual new line.
```

The HTTP command would be **POST http://localhost:9200/schools_gov/_bulk**

Answer (score 0):

As the error states, you simply need to add a new line to the end of the file. 
If you are on a *nix system, you can do this:

```
echo "\n" >> Downloads/bob/test.json
```

Also, as explained in the documentation https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-bulk.html, the `Content-Type` should be `application/x-ndjson`

> When sending requests to this endpoint the Content-Type header should
>   be set to application/x-ndjson

So the command should be:

```
curl -XPOST -H 'Content-Type: application/x-ndjson' localhost:9200/_bulk --data-binary Downloads/bob/test.json
```

Comment: @tomak, You know better as I don't have access to the file.

Comment: That is what I don't understand. The file has a newline at the end of it but somehow, it doesn't understand that

Comment: @tomak try to explicitly add '\n' to the end.

Comment: I changed the file to this: {"index":{"_id":"53e23f5ae4b0ef99cb360835"}}\n
\n

Comment: @tomak, check my update about `Content-Type: application/x-ndjson`

Answer (score 0):

The error message is very confusing. I typed `-data-binary` and got the same message. The message sent me to completely wrong direction.